# Find the latest entry amongst same number with a Dash?

Tags: sql-server

We have a table that stores a list of all the quotes we have sent out.

Anytime a customer revises the quotes, the system automatically appends a -1 or -2 based on last used number.

As an example

Original Quote Number :  24545

Customer asked for a revision, the quote number is now 24545-1, after sending the quote, we now have a revision again and the Quote is 24545-2 and so on.

I want to run a SQL query that will show them their Top 20 Quotes and incase of revisions, it should show the latest revisions.

Can you please help me?

I have already written a Query that would bring me top 20 quotes for the last 10 days.

```
SELECT Top 20
          EstimateNumber,CustName,JobDescription,TotalSellPrice,EstimateStatus,EstimateDate,CommissionTableA
          FROM [Enterprise32].[dbo].[tablename1]
          where EstimateDate BETWEEN DATEADD(Day, -10, getdate()) AND GETDATE() AND SalesRepCode = $id And TotalSellPrice > '5000' AND EstimateStatus = 'P'
          Order By TotalSellPrice DESC
```

Comment: The fact that you are storing the value `24545-1` inherently means that your Quote "Number" cannot be a Number; `'24545-1'` would have to be stored as a `varchar`. To me, it seems that you should be storing the revision number separately to the Quote Number. Otherwise, if you have 10 revisions you're going to have problems, as `'24545-10'` has a **lower** value than `'24545-2'`

Comment: Hi Larnu, thank you for your reply. The issue here is, this is an external 3rd Party Sofware that we bought few years back. We have no control over the data design.

Comment: I ***assume*** `EstimateNumber` is your "quote number"?

Comment: The assumption is correct. EstimateNumber is my quote number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes some assumptions, but I *think* this might work. If not, sample data and expected result will be invaluable:

```
USE Enterprise32;
GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.EstimateNumber,
           V.RevisionNumber,
           TN1.CustName,
           TN1.JobDescription,
           TN1.TotalSellPrice,
           TN1.EstimateStatus,
           TN1.EstimateDate,
           TN1.CommissionTableA,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.EstimateNumber ORDER BY V.RevisionNumber DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.TableName1 TN1
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-',TN1.EstimateNumber),0)))CI(I)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(int,LEFT(TN1.EstimateNumber,ISNULL(CI.I,LEN(TN1.EstimateNumber))-1)),ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(int,STUFF(TN1.EstimateNumber,1,CI.I,'')),0)))V(EstimateNumber,RevisionNumber)
    WHERE TN1.EstimateDate BETWEEN DATEADD(Day, -10, getdate()) AND GETDATE()
      AND TN1.SalesRepCode = $id
      And TN1.TotalSellPrice > '5000'
      AND TN1.EstimateStatus = 'P')
SELECT TOP (20)
       EstimateNumber,
       RevisionNumber,
       CustName,
       JobDescription,
       TotalSellPrice,
       EstimateStatus,
       EstimateDate,
       CommissionTableA
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: This is awesome, that did work. However one small issue that I saw was the Estimate Number for the revisions do not print out. It shows that the latest revision is 7 but the Estimate Number associated to it does not show.

Comment: `EstimateNumber` is in the `SELECT` @ParthKadakia, but I split out the Quote Number and the Revision number.

Comment: Yes and when the Split happens, the Quote Number or Estimate Number is not shown.

Comment: Yes they are: `SELECT TOP (20)
       EstimateNumber,
       RevisionNumber,`

Comment: I get the following EstimateNumber RevisionNumber CustName JobDescription TotalSellPrice EstimateStatus EstimateDate CommissionTableA
NULL 7 Vans Being Green Book xxxxx P 2019-10-22 00:00:00.000

Comment: As you can see the EstimateNumber is displayed as NULL

Comment: OK, `NULL`, isn't the same as "does not print out". That tells me the problem, and fixed, @ParthKadakia ,. Don't forget I don't have access to your server, so I can't test

Comment: Hi Larnu, completely understand. Based on your edited code, I now get Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '41259-' to data type int.

Comment: Maybe that, @ParthKadakia , if not, see my closing statement *"If not, sample data and expected result will be invaluable:"*.

Comment: No worries, thanks for all your help. I will take a look.

Comment: I am new here, how do I provide you with Sample Data and Expected Result?

Comment: Either as DDL statements or as tabular format `text` works well, @ParthKadakia

Answer (score 0):

With some minor changes, it might work, As there is no data sample:

```
SELECT Top 20
    EstimateNumber,CustName,JobDescription,TotalSellPrice,EstimateStatus,EstimateDate,CommissionTableA

FROM [dbo].[tablename1] tt
    LEFT JOIN
    (
--Top 20 quotes Last EstimateNumber with revision
        SELECT T20.RevisionFree_EstimateNumber + 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR,
                MAX(CONVERT(INT, 
                    SUBSTRING(t.EstimateNumber, CHARINDEX('-', EstimateNumber)+1, LEN(EstimateNumber)-CHARINDEX('-', EstimateNumber))))) Last_EstimateNumber 
        FROM
        (
--Top 20 quotes Original EstimateNumber
            SELECT DISTINCT Top 20
                 TotalSellPrice

                ,SUBSTRING(EstimateNumber, 1, CHARINDEX('-', EstimateNumber)) RevisionFree_EstimateNumber

            FROM [dbo].[tablename1]
            where EstimateDate BETWEEN DATEADD(Day, -10, getdate()) AND GETDATE() And TotalSellPrice > '5000' AND EstimateStatus = 'P'
            Order By TotalSellPrice DESC
        )AS T20

        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT *, SUBSTRING(EstimateNumber, 1, CHARINDEX('-', EstimateNumber)) RevisionFree_EstimateNumber 
            FROM [dbo].[tablename1]
        ) t
            ON T20.RevisionFree_EstimateNumber = t.RevisionFree_EstimateNumber
        GROUP BY T20.RevisionFree_EstimateNumber
    )LastEN
        ON tt.EstimateNumber = LastEN.Last_EstimateNumber
```

Comment: Hi Farhad, thank you replying, I am having few issues as Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.

Comment: It's from `Order By`. I will check soon.

Comment: I have revised the query. Please, check and let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: Thank you, will check it out tomorrow when back at office.